# What could be solution for this?

Tags: android

I am not finding the solution for the following problem . Any help?

[image]

Comment: gradle file please

Comment: please show us your code, not an image.. And desribe your problem little bit more.

Comment: add this to your gradle-
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
23.1.1 may change as per your buildToolsVersion in gradle. 
Please research before asking. This is a very basic concept.

Comment: make sure you have **appcompat** dependency in your build.gradle file, if not add **compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'** and do a gradle sync

Comment: Did you changed anything in build.gradle in your  android project

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Add this to your gradle `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'`
2. Go to Build -> Clean Project.
3. Go to File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart.